# How to pull data from server?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

My Object is Food. **`List<Food> contents;`**; How to pull data from server? How to display Food Name? I use this library.

- Here TestRecyclerViewAdapter

https://github.com/florent37/MaterialViewPager/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/github/florent37/materialviewpager/sample/TestRecyclerViewAdapter.java

I change like this in case TYPE_CELL:

```
  view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                            .inflate(R.layout.list_item_card_promotion_item, parent, false);
TextView foodName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_food_name);
foodName.setText(contents.get(0).getName());
                    return new RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
                    };
```

- RecyclerViewFragment

https://github.com/florent37/MaterialViewPager/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/github/florent37/materialviewpager/sample/fragment/RecyclerViewFragment.java

I change like this.

```
mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        NetworkEngine.getInstance().getFood(new Callback<List<Food>>() {
            @Override
            public void success(List<Food> foods, Response response) {
                mContentItems = foods;
                mAdapter = new RecyclerViewMaterialAdapter(new FoodRecyclerViewAdapter(foods));
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < ITEM_COUNT; ++i)
                        mContentItems.add(new Food());
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });
```